# Unable to use secrets in workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a project from the previous agency that uses GitHub actions.
I already tried several attempts but unfortunately, I was not able to solve the problem.

I am stuck at `Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression:`  error.

Here is the action.yml

```
name: Create envfile

on: [ push ]

jobs:

  create-envfile:
 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 
    steps:
    - name: Make envfile
      with:
        envkey_DEBUG: false
        envkey_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
        envkey_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}
        directory: projectName/
        file_name: .env
        fail_on_empty: false
```

And the part of workflow.yml where the build process stops executing

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  flake8-lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Lint
    steps:
      - name: Check out source repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python environment
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"
      - name: flake8 Lint
        uses: py-actions/flake8@v2
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/actions/create_envfile // it stops here
      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It stucks in `- uses: ./.github/actions/create_envfile` part in the workflow

Here is the full error

```
      Error: 
      /home/runner/work/projectName/./.github/actions/create_envfile/action.yml (Line: 16, Col: 27):
       Error: /home/runner/work/projectName/./.github/actions/create_envfile/action.yml (Line: 17, Col: 31):
       Error: /home/runner/work/projectName/./.github/actions/create_envfile/action.yml (Line: 16, Col: 27): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.CLIENT_ID
       Error: /home/runner/work/projectName/./.github/actions/create_envfile/action.yml (Line: 17, Col: 31): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.CLIENT_SECRET
        Error: Fail to load /home/runner/work/projectName/./.github/actions/create_envfile/action.yml
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is because composite actions do not have access to the "secrets" namespace for security reasons. They do have access to the environment variables set by the calling workflow or you can pass in secrets as inputs to the action.

From your comments all you need to do is use the action from the marketplace and not store as your own composite action like so:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3.0
        with:
          envkey_DEBUG: false
          envkey_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
          envkey_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}
          directory: projectName/
          file_name: .env
          fail_on_empty: false

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Got new error `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.CLIENT_ID`

Comment: The layout of your `action.yml` file looks more like a workflow file If it is a composite action check out https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action

Comment: I'm not really into DevOps things, but surely I will spend time learning the basics. I just followed this from GitHub https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-env-file. If you would update the answer to update my action.yml file into composite action I would be glad and really appreciate the help

Comment: Ah okay I understand a bit more now. I will edit my answer above

Comment: this works if directory is ommited, however it doesnt create the .env file if custom directory is added FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/github/workspace/home/runner/work/projectName/projectName/.env'